# Mirror object on x but also flip on Y?

Tags: mirror

I'm mirroring an object across X axis which is fine. But I want to flip on Y after mirror.

I'm using an empty as the mirror object and it only lets me rotate axis using X and Z. It's ignoring the rotation of the Y.

Is this by design or am I doing it wrong?

See sample file at https://github.com/d0n13/blender

Thanks
Donie

Comment: could you please show some pictures or even share your file?

Comment: file added above

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The red object is not a reflection of the green object, wherever you put the mirror. It's a rotation of it. You could get there via 2 reflections, bit the mirror modifier would generate excess objects on the way.

An array modifier can do it using an axis/origin Empty with a rotation in Z of 180, the translation will depend on the origin of your object and the relative position of the Empty ...

[image]