# How to Flip a Mirror Modifier

Tags: modifiers, mirror

I can't figure out how to flip a Mirror Modifier along the Y axis, after it is mirrored.

Would love some advice on how to achieve this, per the below images:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: May I ask why you need the mirror modifier for this and why you can't just model that? The second image seems slightly modified and I can't achieve that same result using a mirror modifier. If you could put it into a little more context in regards to what you're trying to achieve and why you need a mirror modifier to do it then I can better understand and help more. Thanks.

Comment: I'm trying to just freestyle model a new product for my company, and I have an idea of the object being symmetrical horizontally, yet flipped vertically across the horizontal mirror, if that makes sense.  In order to help me design this thing, it would be helpful if the mirror/flip was happening automatically while I'm modeling it. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Simply use the Array modifier instead.

1. Add an empty and flip it in X and Y axis
2. Add *Array modifier > Object Offset* and target the empty
3. Done

<sup>You can flip the empty either by scaling to -1 or through Object > Mirror</sup>
[image]

Comment: .. beat me by 9 minutes ... :D

Comment: I probably learned this trick from you anyways :)

Comment: Yep, definitely: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/194442/78972

Comment: Yours is different, and it's a really nice distinction. The reflections in the _Mirror_ modifier are cumulative. In the _Array_ modifier they are simultaneous.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted, thank you for that ;)

Comment: @glen Glad it works for you, good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 3):

Mirror modifier mirrors the object's geometry in it's local space, so if you select X axis and the geometry is towards the +X direction from the origin of the object it will be mirrored to the -X direction, if the geometry is towards the -X direction from the origin, it will get mirrored to the +X direction. You can change the origin point using transform tools if you have Affect Only Origins enabled in the Active Tool and Workspace settings tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

By manipulating location and rotation of the origin(so object's local space) you can control the mirror modifier. You could also use Mirror Object and in that case the modifier will use the object space of that object:

[image]

In your specific case, it seems that you do not want to mirror the object so mirror modifier is not suitable. You could duplicate linked (<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>) and have another object with the same geometry data and just rotate it the way you want, or you could use the new GeometryNodes modifier and rotate a copy of the geometry:

[image]

Comment: Cool :). Looking forward to experimenting with geometry nodes.

Comment: Thanks man, I appreciate the perspective on this.  Geometry nodes sounds very interesting indeed, can't wait to start learning it.