# How can I mirror this pedal, empty rotation on the x-axes won't work

Tags: mirror, mirror-modifier

[image: Pedal Mirror]

Hello guys,  I believe there is a simple solution to this but I can't figure it out. I want to mirror this pedal in my model as highlighted in the image. I used a mirror modifier on the x-axis to flip the pedal to the other side of the wheel and tried to use an empty object to rotate it but it won't rotate as I want to in the x-axes. I tried different variations of mirroring and rotating but nothing seems to work as I wanted.

Comment: hello, are you allowed to use an armature?

Comment: actually this answer is exactly what you want  https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/213647/20102

Comment: Yupp it is the exact same thing that I was looking for. Thank you so much Luciano!!!

Answer (score 2):

You can create one object for the crank arms, 2 objects for the pedals (each time, duplicate then press <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>-1</kbd> to mirror as explained by Chris), make sure that the origin is at the rotation axis. Create 2 empties, put them at the tip of the arms and parent them to the object, give your pedals a *Copy Location* constraint with the empties as *Target*:

[image]

Now when you rotate the crank arms the pedals follow but don't rotate:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

i would select your object in object mode, then Shift-D S -1

[image]

Comment: Yea I first did that first but I need the same 2D map on the UV editor so I'm trying to do it like this.